# Xamarin Forms Dependeny Injected HttpClient Timeout not working when API is down

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, singleton, dotnet-httpclient

After some research, I've learned that creating new HttpClients with every request is not a good use of HttpClient. Using Dependency Injection is one of the best solutions. So, I've implemented DI in my Xamarin Forms App, but I'm running into an issue. I have the client-side service as a Singleton and am injecting the httpclient into it. The httpclient timeout property works if the API is running. Unfortunately, when the API is not running, the timeout does not work. It takes over two minutes for an exception to occur even when I set the http timeout to 10 seconds. I'm expecting an exception to occur after the set timeout and a message of something like this, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it...", but again nothing happens until over two minutes. However, if I create a new HttpClient, everything works as expected. I've initialized the timeout property in the Startup file and in the Service constructor, but there's no difference. When the API is not running, the httpclient's timeout does not work. I would really appreciate any help with this. See the link to the article I used as a reference below. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you in advance!!!

[Xamarin Forms Dependency Injection Article](https://montemagno.com/add-asp-net-cores-dependency-injection-into-xamarin-apps-with-hostbuilder/)

EDIT:

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public static void Init()
    {
      var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
                {
                  c.AddCommandLine(new string[] { $"ContentRoot={FileSystem.AppDataDirectory}" });
                })
                .ConfigureServices((c, x) => ConfigureServices(c, x))
                .Build();

      //Save our service provider so we can use it later.
      ServiceProvider = host.Services;
    }

    static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddHttpClient("", client =>
      {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
      });
      services.AddSingleton<IMyAppService, MyAppService>();
      services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
    }
  }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public class MainViewModel
  {
    public ICommand CallAPICommand
    {
      get
      {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
          try
          {
            var races = await _appService.CallApiAsync();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
          }
        });
      }
    }

    IMyAppService _appService;
    public MainViewModel(IMyAppService appService)
    {
      _appService = appService;
    }
  }
}
```

MyAppService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public class MyAppService : IMyAppService
  {
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyAppService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    //public MyAppService(HttpClient client)
    {
      httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
      //httpClient = client;
    }

    public async Task<string> CallApiAsync()
    {
      //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("YOUR API CALL HERE");

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

IMyAppService.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public interface IMyAppService
  {
    Task<string> CallApiAsync();
  }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingContext = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<MainViewModel>();
    }
  }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HttpClientTimeoutTest.MainPage">

  <StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
      <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
    </Frame>
    <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
    <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>
    <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">
      <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
          <FormattedString.Spans>
            <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
            <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
      </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
    <Button Command="{Binding CallAPICommand}" Text="Call API"/>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

WebAPI  HttpClientTimeoutTestController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class HttpClientTimeoutTestController : ControllerBase
  {
    public HttpClientTimeoutTestController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
      //Thread.Sleep(60000);
      return Ok(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, properly formatted, in the body of your question.  Linking to offsite repos is against SO guidelines.  Please read [ask] for guidance.

Comment: My apologies. I have modified my post with the important code necessary to reproduce my issue. Please let me know if there's something else I missed. Thank you.

Comment: The ASP.NET core host builder stuff is definitely overkill here. You could register a singleton using the Xamarin.Forms dependency service. You could create a singleton using a static class, you could put your httpclient in the app.cs file (which is itself a singleton). I personally use a DI container for my xamarin apps (Prism) and register my clients as singletons and have no issues like you described. I would imagine the host builder is doing something funky since its not designed for this application.

Comment: Wow. Overkill is an understatement. :) I didn't know much about the built-in DependencyService for XF. Thank you for that reference. All I had to do was register my Service as a Singleton in the App.xaml.cs file using DependencyService.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. So I removed the Startup.cs file from my project and simply registered my Service as a Singleton:

App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    public HttpClient Client { get; set; }
    public App()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Client = new HttpClient();
      Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
      var appService = new MyAppService(Client);
      DependencyService.RegisterSingleton<IMyAppService>(appService);
      MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I assign the value of my Singleton to a variable to be injected in my ViewModel like below:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HttpClientTimeoutTest
{
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      var service = DependencyService.Get<IMyAppService>();
      BindingContext = new MainViewModel(service);
    }
  }
}
```

I've tested and retested this and my timeouts work perfectly even when the API is not running. I've also implemented this into my "REAL" app and everything work there also. Including the header tokens on the httpclient being injected. If this can be simplified even more, please let me know, but so far so good. Thanks again @**Axemasta**.